# Android google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, google-maps-api-2

Hi i used google map v2 and if i run app

```
public class SocMap extends Activity {

}
```

open map but i if run app

```
public class SocMap extends FragmentActivity {

}
```

app crash

error:

```
04-28 15:10:03.405: E/AndroidRuntime(12041): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-28 15:10:03.405: E/AndroidRuntime(12041): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.socmap/com.example.socmap.SocMap}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
04-28 15:10:03.405: E/AndroidRuntime(12041): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #6: Error inflating class fragment
04-28 15:10:03.405: E/AndroidRuntime(12041): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement Google maps in your application and you want your application to target API < 11 then you will have to use the `FragmentActivity`. `FragmentActivity` is part of `google-support-v4` library and basically gives you support for fragment for system prior to API level 11. in this case you would have to import this library. you can get an idea of how it's done by reading step 4 of this blog post I wrote on Google Maps integration:

[Google Maps API V2](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=435)

You just have to remember that if this is the way you go you should use the `SupportMapFragment` object for you map instead of the `MapFragment` you are using currently.

If on the other hand you develop you app to API's level 11 and higher this step is not necessary and you simply can use a simple `Activity` with a `MapFragment`.

Answer (score 0):

See my blog posts i have tried to summarize all there is needed to build an App with Google Maps API V2 for Android.

1. [Solution to Problems with Maps API V2(using google_play_services_lib).](http://mzubair.com/solving-the-problemserrors-of-google-maps-api-v2/)
2. [Creating an Android App with Maps API V2 for minSDK=8 (Android 2.2 Froyo).](http://mzubair.com/creating-an-android-app-with-maps-api-v2/)
3. [Creating an Android App with Maps API V2 for minSDK=11 (Android 3.0 HoneyComb).](http://mzubair.com/creating-an-android-app-with-maps-api-v2-for-minsdk11-android-23-0-honeycomb/)

Answer (score 0):

In your layout it looks like your using a MapFragment. Use `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"` instead and in your `onCreate`, get the MapFragment like so:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment); //your SupportMapFragment's id will need to be set to this in your layout.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this project you'll have all your answer regarding Google Map v2.

[Android Working with Google Map V2](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/08/android-working-with-google-maps-v2/)

Answer (score 0):

Your error trace shows `ClassCastException`

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.Fragment

It means You are using API less than 11 with `FragmentActivity` and `MapFragment`. Try to update API > 11 with `Activity` and `MapFragment`.

If you want to continue with API < 11 then use `SupportMapFragment` instead of `MapFragment`.

Refer this to implement MapFragment with API > 11 [Google Map v2](https://www.androidlearninghub.com/2018/09/android-with-google-map-v2.html)